# Winforms datagrid :How the bind datagrid with list of derived classes

Tags: c#, winforms, datagrid

I'm facing a problem with winforms datagrids binding.

i have a base class A, this class is inherited by A1 and A2

```
public class A
{
  public string P {get;set;}
}

public class A1 : A
{
  public string P1 {get;set;}
}

public class A2 : A
{
  public string P2{get;set;}
}
```

i have also a list i want to display in a grid

```
List<A> Mylist = new List<A>();

MyList.add(new A1());
MyList.add(new A2());
```

The grid has 2 columns, the first column displays the value of P, the second column displays P1 or P2.

How can i do this ?

Regards,

Moon

Answer (score 1):

Design your classes like this:

```
public class A
  {
    public string P { get; set; }
    public virtual string VirtualString { get; set; }
  }

  public class A1 : A
  {
    public string P1 { get; set; }

    public override string VirtualString
    {
      get { return P1; }
      set { P1 = value; }
    }
  }

  public class A2 : A
  {
    public string P2 { get; set; }

    public override string VirtualString
    {
      get { return P2; }
      set { P2 = value; }
    }
  }
```

You need a common base for any custom behavior in your derived classes.